# Memory leaks when initialising and populating linked list C

Tags: c, valgrind, singly-linked-list

I am very new to C programming, debugging and programming in general which I am currently studying. For an assignment, I am getting some undefined behaviour when trying to use functions that use a linked list I have created. Specifically, nodes will 'disappear' after I've tried to access them and when comparing user entered values to those stored in the list it only work for some functions or on certain values. I believe I have a memory leak which is causing this, so I ran my program through valgrind and got this leak summary at once completed:

```
==17339== 
==17339== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17339==     in use at exit: 336 bytes in 6 blocks
==17339==   total heap usage: 16 allocs, 10 frees, 1,723 bytes allocated
==17339== 
==17339== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==17339==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64- 
linux.so)
==17339==    by 0x402972: system_init (tm_utility.c:41)
==17339==    by 0x400AC0: main (tm.c:50)
==17339== 
==17339== 320 bytes in 5 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==17339==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-
linux.so)
==17339==    by 0x401FC6: populate_stock_list (tm_stock.c:44)
==17339==    by 0x402CB6: load_data (tm_utility.c:122)
==17339==    by 0x400AEF: main (tm.c:57)
==17339== 
==17339== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17339==    definitely lost: 336 bytes in 6 blocks
==17339==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17339==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17339==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17339==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17339==
```

Here is the structs of my list:

```
typedef struct stock_list * stock_list_ptr;
typedef struct coin * coin_list_ptr;
typedef struct tm {
    coin_list_ptr coins;
    stock_list_ptr stock;
} tm_type;

struct stock_data 
{
    char ticket_name[TICKET_NAME_LEN+1];
    char ticket_type;
    char ticket_zone[TICKET_ZONE_LEN+1];
    unsigned int ticket_price;
    unsigned int stock_level;
};
typedef struct stock_node 
{
    struct stock_data * data;
    struct stock_node * next_node;
} stock_node;

struct stock_list
{
    stock_node * head_stock;
    unsigned int num_stock_items;
};
```

Here is the functions where the memory losses occur:

```
BOOLEAN system_init(tm_type * tm)
{
   if((tm->coins=malloc(sizeof(struct coin) * NUM_COINS)) == NULL) {
      return FALSE;
   } 
   memset(tm->coins, 0, (sizeof(struct coin)*NUM_COINS));
   if((tm->stock=malloc(sizeof(struct stock_list))) == NULL) {
      return FALSE;
   }

   tm->stock->head_stock = NULL;
   tm->stock->num_stock_items =0;

   return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN populate_stock_list(tm_type *tm, char  *ticket_name, char ticket_type, 
                char *ticket_zone, unsigned int ticket_price,
                unsigned int stock_level, unsigned int stock_count)
{
   stock_node *new_node;
   if(tm->stock == NULL) {
      return FALSE;
   }
   if((new_node = malloc(sizeof(stock_node))) == NULL) {
      return FALSE;
   }

   new_node->data = malloc(sizeof(struct stock_data));
   strcpy(new_node->data->ticket_name, ticket_name);
   new_node->data->ticket_type = ticket_type;
   strcpy(new_node->data->ticket_zone , ticket_zone);
   new_node->data->ticket_price = ticket_price;
   new_node->data->stock_level = stock_level;
   new_node->next_node = tm->stock->head_stock;
   tm->stock->head_stock = new_node;
   tm->stock->num_stock_items = stock_count;
   return TRUE;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why I am getting leaks here? Is it because the memory isn't elsewhere in the program so the it is lost when the function ends? Thanks!

Comment: Dont typedef pointers; you will confuse yourself, and others.

Comment: #typedef pointers if you want to, and know what you're doing. You will help readability, sometimes. Do what's most intuitive to you, and be consistent.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments. The typedef declarations  I can't do anything about as it was provided to me as start up code by my instructor. I am not allowed to edit those. @wildplasser are you talking about in the populate_stock_list() where I have created the temp_node or do you mean the declarations in with my stock structs?